# In nested iterators accessing vector by index does not work

Tags: rust, iterator, closures

I have a strange behavior that I cannot explain to myself. If want to create new Strings by iterating over two `Vec<String>`'s, but somehow access by index doesn't work, because I borrow stuff. My confusion comes from the fact that the index should not be copied as it is a primitive time.

The example *does* work if I iterate directly over the `Vec<String>`'s. The compiler error's suggestion of using `move` in the second `map` does not fix the problem.

Here is my example:

```rust
fn f() -> Vec<String> {
    let num_outer = 2;
    let num_inner = 3;

    let outer_names = vec!["1", "2"];
    let inner_names = vec!["x", "y", "z"];

    (0..num_outer)
        .into_iter()
        .map(|outer_index| {
            (0..num_inner).into_iter().map(|inner_index| {
                format!(
                    "tuple ({},{})",
                    outer_names[outer_index], inner_names[inner_index],
                )
            })
        })
        .flatten()
        .collect::<Vec<String>>()
}

fn main() {
    let x = f();

    println!("{:?}", &x);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you need your closures to capture the indices by `move` (or by `Copy`, since they're `Copy` types), but also capture the `Vec`s by reference. Rust only lets you choose one type of capture syntactically (it's by `move` if you make a `move` closure, otherwise it captures everything by reference).

However, it's easy to do it manually. You just use a `move` closure and "move-in" references that you create before the closure. In your case, this works:

```rust
fn f() -> Vec<String> {
    let num_outer = 2;
    let num_inner = 3;

    let outer_names = vec!["1", "2"];
    let inner_names = vec!["x", "y", "z"];

    let outer_names_ref = &outer_names;
    let inner_names_ref = &inner_names;
    (0..num_outer)
        .flat_map(|outer_index| {
            (0..num_inner).map(move |inner_index| {
                format!(
                    "tuple ({},{})",
                    outer_names_ref[outer_index], inner_names_ref[inner_index],
                )
            })
        })
        .collect::<Vec<String>>()
}

fn main() {
    let x = f();

    println!("{:?}", &x);
}
```

Note I also removed the unnecessary `into_iter`s, since the range literals are already iterators. I also switched to `flat_map` because clippy suggested it (use clippy! it's great :) )

---

In general, if you need "mixed captures" for a closure (i.e., move captures for some variables, reference captures for others), this is the way to do it. You use a `move` closure, but you explicitly create the references that you need to move in to capture things "by reference".

Comment: The default isn't to capture everything by reference, but by the first of reference, exclusive reference, move that does work with the semantics. I.e. `let x = String::new(); let f = || x;` [does indeed move `x`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=601c109fa41fb9f2e1c15ef73535637a)

Comment: Also as a tip, if you [capture just before the closure you can shadow the old variables and avoid having to think of new names](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d4f3e6586b1b5e5f81efd13e704d9956) that's a common way to specify the things that should not be moved, or for example clone `Arc` that should be shared.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the same thing can also be written much shorter using 2 loops:

```
fn f() -> Vec<String> {
    let num_outer = 2;
    let num_inner = 3;
    let outer_names = ["1", "2"];
    let inner_names = ["x", "y", "z"];

    let mut rslt = vec![];
    for outer in outer_names.iter().take(num_outer) {
        for inner in inner_names.iter().take(num_inner) {
            rslt.push(format!(
                "tuple ({outer}, {inner})"
            ));
        }
    }
    rslt
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=2cbdf5c2fbb96a729288a08f158e6730)

Comment: yes, that works, too. I used that version for a while. I mainly wanted to understand the reason behind this error when using induces into arrays.

Comment: I see. In productive code, however, I would prefer this 2 loop solution because of the clarity and the higher speed.

Comment: Yes, of course! It was merely a problem that occurred in something that I wrote where It had to be like this. I made this simple example only to illustrate the question in a simpler way.